# Dual layer DVD question

Tags: optics, laser-driver

I'm curious how a laser knows which layer to read in a single side dual layer DVD. It seems like it could easily read data from the second layer while it's shining through scanning the first.

Answer (score 4):

The lenses used by those DVD players have an extraordinarily shallow "depth of focus". They can easily focus on the inner layer and the outer layer will be WAY out of focus.  It is easier to do this with shorter wavelengths of light (toward blue and ultra-violet).  This is one of the reasons why the HD version of DVD uses "Blue-Ray" or shorter-wavelength light.

Commercial versions of dual-layer discs are moulded as two separate layers with different data patterns, and then laminated together. Field-recordable discs are written by focusing the lens on either the inner or outer layer.

Comment: Ok so the player tells the laser to either focus less/more depending on which layer needs to be read?

Comment: It is not exactly the notion of "focus less/more". By moving the lens toward the disc, they can focus on the INNER layer, and by moving away from the disc, they can focus on the SURFACE layer.
The point of focus is a fixed distance from the lens. Just as you arm has a fixed length. To reach something at the front of the fridge, you can just grab it. But to reach something toward the back, you must move closer to the fridge to be able to reach farther in.

Comment: Oh so the len's focus is fixed but the whole lens assembly moves closer or further away as needed per layers?

Comment: Yes the lens moves so that the beam focuses on either the outer (bottom) layer, or the inner layer.  There are two electromagnets that move the lens. One of them moves the lens toward or away from the disk surface (for focus and layer selection). And the other coil moves the lens left/right to keep the beam aligned to the track of data "pits" which form the ones and zeroes. Here is a close-up photo of a typical optical drive lens assembly showing the voice-coils: http://www.petervis.com/CD_and_DVD_Players/cd-player-laser-assembly/cd-player-laser-lens-assembly/cd-player-laser-lens-assembly.gif

Comment: Even ordinary DVDs use visible red light, compared to CD's infrared.